# how to split two decimal numbers inside the brackets using python

Tags: python

I tried sentiment analysis using python to store the final value of sentiment but it has two decimal number for eg (0.2,0.5), I need to split that number because I want first digit number to ignored another number.. I want the result like 0.2

Comment: Whats the format of `(0.2,0.5)`? and can you show your code and what you have tired so far for solve your problem, till we could figure out whats your mean?

Comment: It it is a tuple, just take the first item by index (`[0]` in python). If it's a string formatted the way you wrote it, you can use `eval` to transform that string into a tuple and treat it as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

If `(0.2,0.5)` a string.

```
>>> s = '(0.2,0.5)'
>>> s.split(',')[0].lstrip('(')
'0.2'
```

If `(0.2,0.5)` a tuple.

```
>>> s = (0.2,0.5)
>>> s[0]
0.2
```

Comment: Thank you so much I got output @ Avinash Raj